# Photos do not back up to OneDrive

Tags: onedrive, photos, backup

Nokia Lumia 520 with Lumia Denim.

I have three Windows Phones (all 8.1) and two of them back up photos to OneDrive, but one does not.

I have of course turned on this feature, and I only connect via WiFi (have disabled cellular data, same as on my other phones).

But the photos never backup to OneDrive, unless I manually share them with OneDrive.

Is there something I have missed to get this to work?